# To Slow Joomla Site in all browsers

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i have a site without heavy content in main page but load to slow.
hn-emdad.ir
in the main page i have the following modules:
a maximenu
a DJ image slider
two ZF simple marquee
sp news highlit
and a 184KB swf header
that's all.
the template made by artisteer and the joomla version is 25.11
please help me to improve the speed

Comment: This is not really the site where to ask this type of questions. There are several tools to know which part of the site is causing it to load slowly, such as [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130621_8Z_Y6X/1/details/). However, i think it's just your connection, for me it loads in under 2secs

Comment: Try to minify CSS, JS, join CSS into one file and JS into one file.
Try to get rid of swf- try to replace it with jquery/javascript 
I have pretty good connection, it takes me about 7 seconds to full load.

Answer (score 0):

i test this in chrome's "inspect element" feature when i have a slow loading page. Open "inspect element" go to the "network" tab and refresh the page. It will show you a time(latency) as each element loads, and you can narrow down where your bottleneck is.